# What is the robot_pose_ekf current state?

Tags: navigation, odometry, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know if the package robot_pose_ekf is going to achieve the roadmap goals in electric. Or if someone is working in it.
We are very interested in this package since we started to work in a package very similar that mixes Odometry.msg from different sensors and finally gives a filtered odometry.
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10757/what-is-the-robot_pose_ekf-current-state?/) by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 843 on 2011-07-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of anyone working to extend the robot_pose_ekf, but I'd be happy to help out anyone that's interested in building upon the codebase. Also note that the stack is already frozen for the upcoming Electric release, so new features will only make it into Fuerte.

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2011-07-29**:
Thanks Wim. I'll let you know if  we try to extend the robot_pose_ekf.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-07-28**:
Yes, Fuerte is the release after Electric.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-28**:
What is Fuerte? The version after Electric?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I second the notion, and would be interested in participating if an effort gets going.

---

Originally posted by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) with karma: 682 on 2011-12-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sethu chidam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2825/sethu-chidam/) on 2012-07-18**:
same here. I am also interested

**Comment by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) on 2012-07-26**:
There seems to be interest forming, follow the thread at [robot_pose_ekf and gps](http://answers.ros.org/question/39790/robot_pose_ekf-and-gps/?comment=39905#comment-39905)